# Installing a pip package with cupy as a requirement puts install in never ending loop

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, cupy

I am trying to make a pip package with cupy as one of the requirements, but I include cupy in the requirement, the pip install ends up in a never ending loop. I am trying to install the package on Google Colab, which already has Cupy install, so it should only check if Cupy is already installed and not try to install it again.

I made a minimal pip package in github where cupy is the only requirement.

https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/TroubleShootCupyInstall

I tried to install it in Google Colab with

```
!pip install --verbose https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/TroubleShootCupyInstall/archive/master.zip --log 'file.log'
```

The output is a lot since it is in verbose, but these are the lines which are printed when it gets to its loop.

```
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_FORCE_INLINES=1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cupy/cuda/nvtx.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/cuda/nvtx.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/cuda/nvtx.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lnvToolsExt -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/cuda/nvtx.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,--disable-new-dtags,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  building 'cupy.cuda.thrust' extension
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_FORCE_INLINES=1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cupy/cuda/thrust.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/cuda/thrust.o
  NVCC options: ['--generate-code=arch=compute_30,code=compute_30', '--generate-code=arch=compute_50,code=compute_50', '--generate-code=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60', '--generate-code=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61', '--generate-code=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70', '--generate-code=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75', '--generate-code=arch=compute_70,code=compute_70', '-O2', '--compiler-options="-fPIC"']
  /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -D_FORCE_INLINES=1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c cupy/cuda/cupy_thrust.cu -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cupy/cuda/cupy_thrust.o --generate-code=arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 --generate-code=arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 --generate-code=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 --generate-code=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 --generate-code=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 --generate-code=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 --generate-code=arch=compute_70,code=compute_70 -O2 --compiler-options="-fPIC"
```

For convenience I made a Google Colab notebook which runs this line, and has the full output.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DFR78cJ07KaHkJfpjh8370SxNw0HXI50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CuPy currently provides source package named `cupy` and binary distribution packages named `cupy-cudaXX` (where XX is a CUDA version).
Currently Google Colab is shipped with `cupy-cuda100` because it is using CUDA 10.0.
If you specify `cupy` as an requirement of your package, `cupy` source package will be downloaded and installed (requires build which takes several minutes), even though CuPy is already available through `cupy-cuda100`.

Unfortunately, Python package distribution tools (such as `setuptools`, `pip`, etc.) do not provide a way to well-handle this kind of complex package composition.

### Workaround 1

In `setup.py` (or in your package's `__init__.py`)

```py
try:
  import cupy
except Exception:
  raise RuntimeError('CuPy is not available. Please install it manually: https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#install-cupy')

# You can also use `cupy.__version__` and `numpy.lib.NumpyVersion` to test CuPy version requirement here.
```

### Workaround 2

Manually check requirements using `pkg_resources` (part of `setuptools`) as done in Chainer.

- https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v6.3.0/chainer/_environment_check.py#L44
- https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v6.3.0/chainer/_version.py#L4-L18